# How to create a poll on IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, polling

hi I’m new to IOS development  i have developed only one application in iOS now i want to make a polling app in IOS  i Google every where i did’t get a proper solution to make a polling app.

In my polling app i want get input poll form the user and i have to store in database and i have to calculate the value for the polling and i have to show the result how many people voted .

so please can any one suggest what is right way to make polling in IOS or is there any alternative way to make this.

thanks.

Comment: "... i have no idea how to make it". You need to LEARN how to make it (with books, tutorials and so many resources online) and then come back to ask specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to store your results on a back end web server with a DB then you would first need to write some web services. I personally would suggest a combination of PHP and MySQL as they're both open source and relatively easy to get to grips with. I also recommend you use JSON as your data interchange format as it provides a human readable structure without the complexity of XML.

Once you have a functioning back end you would need to build an app with the appropriate data fields that you want in either one or multiple views. Personally I would put all of your questions into an array and then cycle through them changing the input controls if necessary. You can then add your answers to an NSMutableArray.

Once you have your complete answer set in your NSMutableArray you can serialise it to JSON and transmit it off to your web service.

There are many guides for getting started with JSON on iOS available, I would suggest you [take a look at this one.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is business specific (not to iOS, iPhone & objective C). 
So I would suggest you to better try these APIs available in market.

[support.polldaddy.com](http://support.polldaddy.com)

[Poll EveryWhere](http://api.polleverywhere.com)

[TypeForm](http://www.typeform.com)

Hope that helps.